# Titanium Properties API usage

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-mobile, appcelerator-mobile

I'm new to Titanium Properties API. I'm getting a weird error when using setObject() method.
Following is my code.

```
Titanium.App.Properties.setObject(view.idAttr, view);
```

Where view.idAttr is a string acting as a key for this property and view is a View type object. Upon calling above method, I get following message.

```
2012-09-14 17:47:25.947 SumMeUp[14033:4a03] *** -[NSUserDefaults setObject:forKey:]: Attempt to insert non-property value '[object TiUIView]' of class 'TiUIViewProxy'.  Note that dictionaries and arrays in property lists must also contain only property values.
```

I couldn't understand this behavior. If anyone knows a solution to, please reply.

Thanx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setObject()` is meant for objects only, not for views.

A object would be something you write yourself in JavaScript.

Even if it could, it would be bad behaviour of the app to store it in a property. Remember the property is being stored cross-session. So if you want something stored, store data there to generate the view later again, not the view itself. Also saves a lot of memory!